# How to update a field existing inside map of document in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've kinda figured out that we can update just one field inside the map of the document

[image]

Like here I can add one more field to courses key, like

```
Map<String, Object> nested = new HashMap(){};
nested.add("sample field inside courses");
```

and passing it to another like

```
Map<String, Object> courses = new HashMap(){};
courses.add();
```

***Q.*** How can I update the value of `abbreviation_color` which is the last field in the above image?

Comment: Have you solved the update problem?

Comment: No, I kinda have to create nested maps!

Comment: So the nested maps solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, it's very hectic

Comment: @AlexMamo I think I've got a solution, check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my test document:

[image: 1]

---

If I now want to update "Test2" I simply call...

```kotlin
yourDocumentReference.update("a.b2.c2", "New Value")
```

which results in this:

---

[image: 2]

---

**Edit**: It does not care if it contains spaces or not, if "b2" would be "b 2" you could easily call

```kotlin
yourDocumentReference.update("a.b 2.c2", "New Value")
```

---

I hope I could help somebody!

Comment: What if b2 had space in it, like 'b 2'

Comment: Then you call 'yourDocumentReference.update("a.b 2.c2", "New Value")'